# How to 'check' all checkboxes in the list to 'check' the single checkbox?

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2, checkbox

I am stuck at a situation in which i have to 'check' all the checkboxes present in the list by 'checking' a checkbox situated in toolbar.

Here's code to create checkbox list:-

```
itemTpl: '<input type="checkbox" name="box" enabled="enabled" value="open" 
name="comment_status" id="status" <tpl if="active">checked="checked"</tpl> />
{groupName}{#}',
```

Here's my checkbox code:-

```
var checkBox = {
            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
              name : 'all',
            //  label: 'All',
              itemId: 'all',
              value: 'all',
              lableWidth: "0",
              width: 1,
              padding: '0 0 15 30',
              checked: false,
              listeners: {
                  check:function() {
                     // alert("check");

                      item = Ext.get("status");
                      console.log("item:-"+Ext.JSON.encode(item));

                      chkBox = item.down('input').dom;

                      var checkboxes = Ext.getStore('group');
                      console.log(checkboxes.getCount());

                      for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.getCount();i++){
                       chkBox.checked = true;
                      }

                  },
                  uncheck:function(){
                     // alert("uncheck");
                  }
              }
        };
```

On the above checkbox check , I want that all the checkboxes defined in "itemTpl" will be checked and vice versa .I know my code inside the check : function(){} is no that good that solve my problem(Both the codes in different views).

So, please advise me some solution of this problem.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Do you have a model associated to your checkboxes ?

Comment: yes,checkbox list has model...

Comment: well, in any case, you have to iterate through your list store, change the boolean corresponding to the checkbox to true for each item and you should be done.

Comment: Yeah that's my idea too but the thing is that i am unable to get the reference of 'itemTpl'.How i can get it?

Comment: Could you add the code of the list and the model associated with the template ?

Comment: you can get the model and list code in http://www.senchafiddle.com/#b4K8w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I updated [your senchafiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#b4K8w#rYgdP) to make it work.
In substance, here is what I added to your code :

Add 2 functions to your list Controller, to manage actions on the checkbox in the toolbar :

```
checkAll:function(){
    this.getCheckboxList().getStore().each(function(record){record.set('active', true);});
},
uncheckAll:function(){
    this.getCheckboxList().getStore().each(function(record){record.set('active', false);});
}
```

And add the toolbar with the checkbox to rule them all (XD) above your list :

```
   {
       xtype : 'toolbar',
       docked: 'top',
       title: 'Check !',
       items:[{
           xtype: 'checkboxfield',
           name : 'all',
           value: 'checkAll',
           listeners:{
               check:function(){
                   MyApp.app.getController('MainViewController').checkAll();
               },
               uncheck:function(){
                   MyApp.app.getController('MainViewController').uncheckAll();
               }
           }
       }]
   }
```

This will need some css on your part to make the ckeckbox nice, but the behaviour is here.

Comment: Thanx for ur answer but i have already done it with help of following code 
  

var items = Ext.getStore('group');
                      items.each(function(record){
                          record.set('active',true);
                      });


Anyways once again thanx for ur support and ur way to do it by controller also seams a good idea.

Comment: Yeah that's the idea. Updating your store automatically updates the view. Using each is the simplest way to iterate through all elements of the store. Controller's way is supposed to be THE proper way to do it in ST2. Though my way could be cleaner with a ref defined on the checkAll checkbox and controls defined on it in your controller !